# listings with background color and mathescape broken

Tags: listings

I have a `listings` environment in my document with `backgroundcolor=\color{grey}` to get a nice grey background and `mathescape=true` for using math symbols. However when using the `\vdots` command inside a code listing I get a break in my listing, as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
language=Lisp,
basicstyle=\small,
backgroundcolor=\color{grey},
mathescape=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
(let ((<$var_1$> <$exp_1$>)
      (<$var_2$> <$exp_2$>)
      $\vdots$
      (<$var_n$> <$exp_n$>))
   <$body$>))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Resulting output:

[image]

So far it's *only* `\vdots` which is doing this (and it happens multiple times so I know it's not a fluke). Is there a fix for this, or maybe would `minted` work better at this sort of thing? (Although I'd rather not switch if I don't have to.)

Comment: Nice question! You could improve the question by providing compilable code with `\documentclass` and everything.

Comment: @Hendrik - Thanks! Ask and ye shall receive.

Comment: And suddenly I don't get `Undefined color \`grey'` anymore `:-)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `listings` expects a constant line height, and that `\vdots` just takes up too much vertical space. One fix is to redefine `\vdots` so that it takes up less vertical space:

```
\renewcommand\vdots{%
  \vbox{\baselineskip3pt\lineskiplimit0pt\kern1pt\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\kern-1pt}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{grey}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
language=Lisp,
basicstyle=\small,
backgroundcolor=\color{grey},
mathescape=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
(let ((<$var_1$> <$exp_1$>)
      (<$var_2$> <$exp_2$>)
      $\makebox(0,7.5){\vdots}$
      (<$var_n$> <$exp_n$>))
   <$body$>))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution eats a bit of the lowest of the three dots. My opinion: Here, a bit of explanation what `\makebox` does would be much more valuable than the full code.

Comment: This doesn't quite work in my document since it shoves the dots to the far left of the page, eating up any indentation. On the other hand, I learned something new about `\definecolor`!

Comment: Replacing `$\makebox(0,7.5){\vdots}$` with `$\makebox(30,8){\vdots}$` (and perhaps an empty line below and above it so everything doesn't look so crammed) makes the lowest dot appear fully and fixes the indentation issue. Note: Adding the empty lines around it also makes the problem that the `\vdots` aren't vertically centered between the code above and below less apparent.

Answer (score 1):

The `listings` package documentation says that you have to use some box tools for this (`tcolotbox`, `mdframed`, etc.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\begin{verbatimwrite}{mycode.lisp}
(let ((<$var_1$> <$exp_1$>)
      (<$var_2$> <$exp_2$>)
      $\vdots$
      (<$var_n$> <$exp_n$>))
   <$body$>))
\end{verbatimwrite}
\lstset{%
language=Lisp,
basicstyle=\small,
mathescape=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[
    backgroundcolor=grey,
    hidealllines=true,
    innertopmargin=0pt,
    innerbottommargin=0pt,
    innerleftmargin=0pt,
    innerrightmargin=0pt
]
\lstinputlisting{mycode.lisp}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]