# Prevent Listings from breaking frames

Tags: listings

Is there any way to prevent the `listings` package from leaving unsightly gaps in the frame when using `breaklines=true`. I'm just `\lstinputlisting` some code, placing it in a `shadowbox` frame and letting `listings` wrap the longer lines. This sometimes causes breaks in the frame (where a line has been split). I've seen [other tex.stackexchange users](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30516/how-to-avoid-background-frame-break-in-code-listings-with-math-mathescape) encounter this problem when embedding maths (or other commands that use more than the expected line height); I'm not attempting anything as exotic. Is this a bug in Listings?

Comment: I am sure you will not the last person who will encounter such an issue. It would be helpful if you composed a small compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrated the problem so that it might help others in the future.  Since you have actually discovered the solution, this should be fairly easy.  This might also explain why no answer appeared either, as it is difficult to fix a problem without first being able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who knows if anyone will ever find this useful, but here goes. I discovered the answer to my problem of the frame becoming broken. It was caused by having spaces in front of keywords in my custom language definition. The gaps always corresponded with where a line had been broken and a keyword was the first item on the remainder of the wrapped line. By ensuring that there were no spaces and only commas between my keywords I rectified the issue.