# Bottom frame of listing appears on top of the next page

Tags: listings, page-breaking

As the title says. I use, among other things, the following in my `lstset`:

```
framerule=1pt,
frame=tblr
```

Some places a page break happens in the middle of my `\lstlisting`. Fine. But sometimes the whole code of the listing appears on one page, but the bottom frame appears on the top of the next page!

[image: Imgur]

I know that I can `float` a particular listing, but I have a long document with many listings, and I don't want to float all of them; Most of them also need to be exactly where they are declared. That they are broken over a page doesn't bother me *that* much.

**Is there something that can stop this from happening, without me needing to adjust each individual listing?**

[This guy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73230/39051) had the same problem, but fixed it by removing spaces in front of keywords in a custom language definition. <s>I too have a custom language definition, but his solution doesn't help me.</s> I managed to recreate the situation without a custom language.

### Edit and MWE

I managed to reproduce it in a minimal working example. [Here](http://pastebin.com/bQV3MSVW)'s a pastebin, if that's helpfull.

```
\documentclass[UKenglish,a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{babel}

%% Adjustments
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{4\baselineskip}
\pretolerance = 2000
\tolerance = 5000   \hbadness = \tolerance

%% Smaller font
\usepackage{mathptmx}

%% LISTINGS
\usepackage[final]{listings}
\lstset{
    xleftmargin=1.5em,
    framexleftmargin=1em,
    framextopmargin=0.5ex,
%%  THE FRAME:
    framerule=1pt,
    frame=tblr
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}     % for demo
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Lorem}   % some fiddling to get the "wrong spacing just right":
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{Ipsum} 
\lipsum[1] and then some text

\begin{lstlisting}
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
\end{lstlisting}

Can you believe it..?!
\end{document}
```

This MWE is rather long. My document inputs most of the listings stuff from files written by others, so I'm not sure what all of it does. If anyone sees some lines that they are *sure* is irrelevant, feel free to take it out of the MWE.

### "Fun fact"

An equally silly situation occurs if you remove `\usepackage{mathptmx}`: The whole code listing will then appear on the new page, except for the top frame which is left on the bottom of the first page!

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add fully compilable (minimum working) example illustrating your situation? That would help solvers tremendously as it is a starting point for them.

Comment: @Malipivo I will try. However, it will probably be hard to reproduce the broken frame when reducing it to a MWE. My document is currently 67 pages long, so posting the whole thing is not an option either.

Comment: @Malipivo There, I managed to reproduce it in a MWE

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Probably related question: [framed - Listings package split frame when the page ends - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169442/listings-package-split-frame-when-the-page-ends)

Answer (score 6):

Frames with `listings` package are known to be problematic.

I've created a new environment `mylisting` with `tcolorbox` that reproduces your `\lstset` but has not those problems.

MWE

```
\documentclass[UKenglish,a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{babel}

%% Adjustments
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{4\baselineskip}
\pretolerance = 2000
\tolerance = 5000   \hbadness = \tolerance

%% Smaller font
\usepackage{mathptmx}

%% LISTINGS
\usepackage[final]{listings}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}
\newtcblisting{mylisting}{
      arc=0pt,
      top=0mm,
      bottom=0mm,
      left=0mm,
      right=0mm,
      colback=white,
      breakable,
      boxrule=1pt,
      listing only,
      listing options={xleftmargin=1.5em,framexleftmargin=1em,framextopmargin=0.5ex}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}     % for demo
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Lorem}   % some fiddling to get the "wrong spacing just right":
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{Ipsum}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{mylisting}
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
\end{mylisting}

Can you believe it..?!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the very powerful `tcolorbox` package that supports `listings`.

Here's an example, the frame can be customized in various ways. I used the optional argument to the `danlisting` environment just to show that you use it for passing options to `lstlisting`. The environment is breakable across pages.

```
\documentclass[UKenglish,a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{babel}

%% Adjustments
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{4\baselineskip}
\pretolerance = 2000
\tolerance = 5000   \hbadness = \tolerance

%% Smaller font
\usepackage{mathptmx}

%% LISTINGS
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}

\newtcblisting{danlisting}[1][]{%
  breakable,
  listing only,
  listing options={#1},
}

%\lstset{
%    xleftmargin=1.5em,
%}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}     % for demo
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Lorem}   % some fiddling to get the "wrong spacing just right":
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{Ipsum} 
\lipsum[1] and then some text

\begin{danlisting}[xleftmargin=1.5em,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
\end{danlisting}

Can you believe it..?!

\begin{danlisting}[xleftmargin=1.5em,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
Here is a listing with
three lines of code;
The bottom border is placed on the next page!
\end{danlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]