# listing with background color broken with maths equation

Tags: color, listings

This is a similar question to [listings with background color and mathescape broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10958/listings-with-background-color-and-mathescape-broken).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{MyGray}{gray}{0.9}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Example}


\begin{lstlisting}[   % 进行参数设置
         basicstyle=\ttfamily,
         backgroundcolor = \color{MyGray},
         breaklines=true, % 自动换行
         frame=tb,
         mathescape=true
    ]
    It is testing.
    $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$
    Testing is over.
    
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

and it shows something like this:

[image]

As we can see, the background color is broken.

According to [listings with background color and mathescape broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10958/listings-with-background-color-and-mathescape-broken), it is because `listings` expects a constant line height. However, its solution there only works for its problem. Are there any general solutions? I have tried `\resizebox` and it works but the mathematical formulations get to be very small.

updated:

By using the package `framed`, it works on certain situation. However, it still doesn't work very well. For example, if I am using the code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.9}

\setlength{\FrameSep}{0pt}
\setlength{\FrameRule}{0pt}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Example}

\begin{shaded}
\begin{lstlisting}[   % 进行参数设置
         basicstyle=\ttfamily\large,
         breaklines=true, % 自动换行
         frame=single,
         mathescape=true,
         belowskip=0pt
    ]
    It is testing.
    $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$
    Testing is over.
    
\end{lstlisting}
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

It still goes wrong like this:

[image]

Comment: It is often better to combine `listings` and the `tcolorbox` package to have `tcolorbox` add decorations to `listings`. See the `tcolorbox` manual.

Comment: Hope this is helpful, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30516/how-to-avoid-background-frame-break-in-code-listings-with-math-mathescape

Answer (score 2):

I believed that, this was a known issue, you can try with the combination of `framed.sty` and `listings.sty`, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.9}

\title{test}

\lstset{%
  mathescape=true,basicstyle=\ttfamily,
         breaklines=true,belowskip=0pt
}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\FrameSep}{0pt}
\setlength{\FrameRule}{0pt}
\maketitle

\section{Example}

\begin{shaded}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=tb]
    It is testing.
    $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$
    Testing is over.
    
\end{lstlisting}
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand ```\FrameSep``` controls the margin of the background color. However, I still don't understand what ```\FrameRule``` is used for. I have looked up the document of the package ```framed ``` but I still don't understand. I would really appreciate it if you can give me some explanations.

Comment: @liaoming999 Just for safety purpose, I would made it into `0pt`, nothing else :-), sorry for the delay in reply