# Unwanted White Lines in listings environment

Tags: spacing, listings

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray}, xleftmargin=0.7cm,
    frame=tlbr, framesep=0.2cm, framerule=0pt,  
}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
k = $\lfloor (10\log n \cdot \log\log n)^{1/3} \rfloor$;
k = $\lfloor (4\log n \cdot \log n)^{1/3} \rfloor$;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: just a picture describing the situation]

An answer to a similar question said that "this line is just an artifact of the viewer". But this line appears in two viewers and various zoom steps. On top of that, one can clearly see that the `1/3` overlaps with the white line. So I do not accept it as a mere artifact anymore.

How could this problem be approached? Is it possible to somehow put another grey layer underneath the lstlisting environment which would "eat up" any white lines?

edit: Is there a solution that would not involve editing every line of the code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is what I was looking for. By putting a grey layer (via mdframed) underneath the listings environment every white line disappears:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}  
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=c++,basicstyle=\linespread{1.1}\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    xleftmargin=0.0cm, frame=t, framesep=0.15cm, framerule=0pt, tabsize=4,
    showspaces=false, showstringspaces=false,showlines=true,
    commentstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{gray},
}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=black!5,leftmargin=0.5cm,hidealllines=true,%
  innerleftmargin=0.2cm,innerrightmargin=0.2cm,innertopmargin=-0.72cm,innerbottommargin=-0.10cm]
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape, caption = This is some code]
k = $\lfloor (10\log n \cdot \log\log n)^{1/3} \rfloor$;    //with caption
k = $\lfloor (4\log n \cdot \log n)^{1/3} \rfloor$;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=black!5,leftmargin=0.5cm,skipabove=0.3cm,hidealllines=true,%
  innerleftmargin=0.2cm,innerrightmargin=0.2cm,innertopmargin=-0.0cm,innerbottommargin=-0.10cm]
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
k = $\lfloor (10\log n \cdot \log\log n)^{1/3} \rfloor$;   //without caption
k = $\lfloor (4\log n \cdot \log n)^{1/3} \rfloor$;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

This question is a duplicate of "[listings with background color and mathescape broken](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10958/16967)". The answers there explain the reason. In short:

The background is drawn by putting a colored rule at the start of each line (hook `EveryLine`). Then the line is typeset. Thus it package `listings` does not know the maximum height and depth of the line. Everything beyond the height and depth of the strut box remains white.

### Workaround `\smash`

`\smash` creates a box, where the height and depth are zero:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray}, xleftmargin=0.7cm,
    frame=tlbr, framesep=0.2cm, framerule=0pt,
}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
k = $\smash{\lfloor (10\log n \cdot \log\log n)^{1/3}\rfloor}$;
k = $\smash{\lfloor (4\log n \cdot \log n)^{1/3} \rfloor}$;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Workaround via increasing the line spacing

If you fear, the lines are too narrow and might touch, then a larger line spacing can be used. Setting of `\baselineskip` in `basicstyle` does not have an effect, but `\fontsize` or `\linespread` with explicit/implicit `\selectfont` work. The following example uses `\linespread` (see [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129413/16967)). `\footnotesize` contains the implicit `\selectfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\linespread{1.15}\footnotesize,   
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray}, xleftmargin=0.7cm,
    frame=tlbr, framesep=0.2cm, framerule=0pt,
}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
k = $\smash{\lfloor (10\log n \cdot \log\log n)^{1/3}\rfloor}$;
k = $\smash{\lfloor (4\log n \cdot \log n)^{1/3} \rfloor}$;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there a solution that does not involve editing every line of the code?

Comment: @Tom: In general no. The background of the line is drawn *before* the line is typeset. Thus everything beyond the height and depth of the strut box remains white.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, your solution really helped, thanks! I wanted to ask, is it possible to set \linespread's value of a specific code listing to another number? Generally 1.1 is good, but there are some listings that still create white lines, and for them I want to specifically set to a bigger value so it won't have the white lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can increase the baseline skip so the lines won't be too near (to the eyes of TeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{basicstyle=\linespread{1.1}\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray}, xleftmargin=0.7cm,
    frame=tlbr, framesep=0.2cm, framerule=0pt,
}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
k = $\lfloor (10\log n \cdot \log\log n)^{1/3} \rfloor$;
k = $\lfloor (4\log n \cdot \log n)^{1/3} \rfloor$;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It only increases the height of each line :/

Comment: @Zorobay Not sure what you mean. I ckecked with a current version of LaTeX and it works exactly the same.

Comment: I think that what this actually does is set the background color the same as the lines. When I use your code but change the 'light-gray' to a darker color, the lines show up again.

Comment: @Zorobay Ask a new question with the details. However, the background is better set with the help of `tcolorbox`.