# How can I reduce the line spacing in a listing?

Tags: listings, line-spacing

I have some listings in my beamer presentation. Sometimes, the last line of the code I want to explain doesn't fit on the slide. I've already configured the font size to scale `.7`:

```
\newfontfamily\listingsfont[Scale=.7]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\lstset{basicstyle=\listingsfont}
```

Is there a possibility to reduce the line spacing in a listing as well?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To reduce the space between lines, you can invoke `\linespread{<x>}` in the value passed to the `basicstyle` key, where `<x>` is a number smaller than 1, as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129413/21891) by egreg. Don't abuse it, though.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\newfontfamily\listingsfont[Scale=.7]{Menlo}

\lstset{frame=single}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\listingsfont]
/* Hello World program */
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\listingsfont]
/* Hello World program */
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be handled by `fontspec` the same way it handles color and word spacing, for instance?

Comment: @Manuel I don't know. I'm not that familiar with `fontspec`, to be honest. Don't hesitate to chime in if you think of a more sensible approach :)

Comment: It was meant to see an opinion if you thought this should be added as a feature request to `fontspec`.

Comment: @Manuel I don't know `fontspec` well enough to have an opinion on that, but note that the use of `fontspec` in my answer is only incidental; I only used it because the OP (presumably) wants to use it. A good solution should be independent of whether `fontspec` is used or not.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of using `fontspec` because I didn't have to add a `\usepackage{fontspec}` and everything is working :-\

Comment: I've just realized that the linespread is also applied to the caption of the listing. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 11):

To reduce the line spacing for all lstlistings, just set

```
basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}
```

in your `\lstset{}` configuration. No need to use `fontspec`.

Comment: Makes no effect (at least in pdflatex)

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me (replace `4.2` with any scale factor you need):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{basicstyle=\linespread{4.2}\selectfont}
\begin{lstlisting}
Hello, world!
Second line.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```