# Pandoc (md to pdf), code block with own line spacing

Tags: xetex, line-spacing, pandoc

I've been rendering my PhD thesis with pandoc using [this](https://github.com/tompollard/phd_thesis_markdown) template. The text has line spacing of 1.5, however there are some code blocks within, that I have been writing with the following command:

````
```{.R .numberLines}
measurementInvariance(semModelMIMICraw, data = semWellComb, group = "caso",
                      estimator = "MLM")
```
````

It looks OK, but the line spacing of 1.5 is also respected within the block.

- Are there any parameters that I could send within the curly brackets that could make the block have a line spacing smaller than the rest of the text. Like 1, for instance?
- Or are there any other options to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works for me:

````
```
{.R .numberLines basicstyle="\linespread{0.8}\normalsize"}
measurementInvariance(semModelMIMICraw, data = semWellComb, group = "caso",
                      estimator = "MLM")
```
````

Basically, since you're going to LaTeX, you can use any attributes from the [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. Refer, also, to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200208/how-can-i-reduce-the-line-spacing-in-a-listing). Note that you'll probably have to replace `\normalsize` with the desired font setting for your code. I was not able to get this to work with JUST using `basicstyle="\linespread{0.8}"`.

Comment: This didn't readily work for me, but just in case it helps someone: using `\linespread{0.8}` by itself just before the code block opening ticks did.