# Lstlisting line color between code lines

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle

I have the following Latex code for VHDL code listing:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[european, siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{nameref} % For reference
\usepackage{hyperref} % url reference
\usepackage{tikz} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{automata} 
\usetikzlibrary[automata]
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % state diagram x and y 
\usepackage{amsmath} % For matrix in state machine
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{beramono} % monospaced font with bold variant
\usepackage{lastpage} % To add lastpage référence.
\usepackage{siunitx} % For microsecond
\usepackage{listings} % Required for insertion of code
\usepackage{eso-pic} % Title background
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,%
keepaspectratio]{background.png}%
\vfill
}}} % For title background


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
% Configuration
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.3622047244, 0.905511811, 0.2204724409}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.3582677165, 0.6338582677, 0.8149606299}
\definecolor{background}{rgb}{0.1062992126, 0.1417322835, 0.1496062992}
\definecolor{text}{rgb}{0.7283464567, 0.7440944882, 0.7165354331}

\definecolor{MyDarkGreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.8,0.0} % This is the color used for comments
\lstloadlanguages{vhdl}
\lstdefinelanguage{vhdl}{
  morekeywords=[1]{
    library,use,all,entity,is,port,in,out,end,architecture,of,
    begin,and,or,Not,downto,ALL, signal, process, if, else, elsif, case, when, then, range, to, component, type, with, select, others, constant, inout, buffer, map, true, false, array, subtype
  },
  morekeywords=[2]{
    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR,STD_LOGIC,IEEE,STD_LOGIC_1164,
NUMERIC_STD,STD_LOGIC_ARITH,STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED,std_logic_vector,
std_logic, ieee, numeric_std, to_signed, to_unsigned, std_ulogic, std_logic_1164, natural, bit, bit_vector, signed, unsigned, boolean, integer
  },
  morecomment=[l]{--}
}
\lstset{language=vhdl, % Use VHDL in this example
        frame=single, % Single frame around code
        %basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, % Use small true type font
        basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\footnotesize\color{red}
        keywordstyle=[1]\color{red}\bf, % VHDL functions bold and blue
        keywordstyle=[2]\color{darkgreen}\bfseries, % VHDL function arguments         purple
        keywordstyle=[3]\color{red}\underbar, % Custom functions underlined and blue
        identifierstyle=, % Nothing special about identifiers
        commentstyle=\usefont{T1}{pcr}{m}{sl}\color{green}\small, % Comments small dark green courier font
        %stringstyle=\color{Red}, % Strings are purple
        showstringspaces=false, % Don't put marks in string spaces
        tabsize=5, % 5 spaces per tab
        %
        % Put standard Perl functions not included in the default language here
        morekeywords={rand},
        %
        % Put Perl function parameters here
        morekeywords=[2]{on, off, interp},
        %
        % Put user defined functions here
        morekeywords=[3]{test, std_logic, std_logic_vector},
        %
        morecomment=[l][\color{blue}]{...}, % Line continuation (...) like blue comment
        numbers=left, % Line numbers on left
        firstnumber=1, % Line numbers start with line 1
        numberstyle=\tiny\color{blue}, % Line numbers are blue and small
        stepnumber=5 % Line numbers go in steps of 5
}
\colorlet{keyword}{blue!100!black!80}
\colorlet{comment}{green!90!black!90}
\lstdefinestyle{vhdl}{
  language     = vhdl,
  basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
  keywordstyle = \color{darkblue}\bfseries,
  commentstyle = \color{darkgreen},
  basicstyle   = \color{text},
  backgroundcolor=\color{background},
  rulecolor    = \color{background},
  breakatwhitespace=false,
}

\setlength{\headheight}{12.1638pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=vhdl]
    entity entityName is
    port (
        a       : in std_logic;
        b       : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        c       : inout std_logic;                          
        d       : buffer std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)       -- never used
    );
end entity ;
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Which produce these annoying lines:
[image: Annoying lines between code lines]

This question was marked as duplicate, but I'm not trying to add a picture, so I can't use another file format to remove the lines. Moreover, unlike the linked question, I do not see any differences when using different PDF viewer.

Comment: Try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129651/117534.