# How to delete white lines generated by listings?

Tags: formatting, color, listings

I am having the exact same issue as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129377/unwanted-white-lines-in-listings-environment), but texstudio's pdf viewer doesn't display the error so i didn't notice until I was 32 pages into the document. His solution actually works (the mdframed one, the others have no effect whatsoever in my case) but I cannot manually traverse 32 pages in a document manually formatting every single code snippet I have. SO I need a solution that will spread across the document (which most likely will involve tweaking the listings environment in the preamble).

I am in a pinch so I made the MWE in 5 minutes, I am sorry.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstset{
    frame=lines,
    rulecolor=\color{deepblue},
    framesep = 5pt,
    language=C,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily\color{cyan}},
    numbers=none,
    %numberstyle=\small\color{green},
    keywordstyle=\color{orange},
    commentstyle=\color{grey},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{deepblue},
    tabsize=3,
    morekeywords={uint32_t},
    keywordsprefix=#
}

\lstdefinestyle{C-small}
{
    language=C,
    morekeywords={uint32_t},
    basicstyle={\fontsize{12}{12}\ttfamily\color{cyan}},
    commentstyle=\color{grey},
    keywordstyle=\color{orange},
}

\lstdefinestyle{C}
{
    language=C,
    morekeywords={uint32_t},
    keywordstyle=\color{orange},
}

\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.15}
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style =C]
    uint32_t mailbox_message[22] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
    uint32_t index;

    void set_init_display_message()
    {
        index = 1;
        mailbox_message[index++] = 0;//request code

        mailbox_message[index++] = (uint32_t) SET_PHYSICAL_WIDTH_HEIGHT; //tag
        mailbox_message[index++] = 8;   //request size
        mailbox_message[index++] = 8;   //response size
        mailbox_message[index++] = physical_width;  //horizontal resolution of the monitor
        mailbox_message[index++] = physical_height; //vertical resolution of the monitor

        mailbox_message[index++] = (uint32_t) SET_VIRTUAL_WIDTH_HEIGHT; //tag
        mailbox_message[index++] = 8;   //rquest size
        mailbox_message[index++] = 8;   // response size
        mailbox_message[index++] = virtual_width;   //horizontal resolution of virtual screen
        mailbox_message[index++] = virtual_height;  //vertical resolution of virtual screen

        mailbox_message[index++] = (uint32_t) SET_DEPTH;    //tag
        mailbox_message[index++] = 4;   //request size
        mailbox_message[index++] = 4;   //response size
        mailbox_message[index++] = color_depth; //color depth of the frame buffer

        mailbox_message[index++] = (uint32_t) ALLOCATE; //tag
        mailbox_message[index++] = 8;   //request size
        mailbox_message[index++] = 8;   //response size
        mailbox_message[index++] = 16;  //alignment fb ptr returned here
        mailbox_message[index++] = 0;   //fb size returned here

        mailbox_message[index++] = END;//end tag

        mailbox_message[0] = index*sizeof(uint32_t);    //size of message
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On a TL17 installation there are no lines for me. Try changing your viewer or zooming in, do you still see the lines? If yes, try updating your distribution.

Comment: It changes depending on the PDF viewer, it's quite annoying, some display it fine some don't

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly a viewer issue and LaTeX cannot change that.

Comment: It is not a viewer issue, depending on how latex formats things no viewer will have problems displaying the text. The fact there are multiple complaints about this limitation of the listings package shows that this is a problem with the package.

Comment: Well, it probably is a viewer issue. If you would take this as a LaTeX issue then the colored tables with horizontal lines would be a LaTeX problem (probably xcolor/colortbl package in your view) and horizontal lines in tables in general, because some viewers mess those up at some zoom levels (more of a LaTeX kernel issue in your view). If those are all LaTeX issues one may feel free to fix them, but there are viewers that do the right interpretation of correct PDFs.