# Math symbols in listings

Tags: listings

Does anyone know how to write math symbols such as sums and integrals inside a listing?

```
\begin{lstlisting}

vl(i)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^N{Al(i,j)*xl(j)}  ;     i = 1,3

\end{lstlisting}
```

UPDATE: Minimal example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{blue!40},numbers=none,language=XML,mathescape=true]
!-----------------------------------------------------

 $vl(i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N{Al(i,j)*xl(j)} ;\quad i = 1,3$

!-----------------------------------------------------
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to "escape to LaTeX".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `mathescape`

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
$vl(i)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^N{Al(i,j)*xl(j)} ;\quad i = 1,3$
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

### EDIT

To avoid blank lines in the background, you can try something with `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!40]
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=none,language=XML,mathescape=true]
!-----------------------------------------------------

 $vl(i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N{Al(i,j)*xl(j)} ;\quad i = 1,3$

!-----------------------------------------------------
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind, that colored backgrounds might be an issue, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10958/listings-with-background-color-and-mathescape-broken

Comment: Ok thanks but this creates a problem.It cuts the background color at the beginning of equations and then restores.Take a look

Comment: @kostas I've edited the answer.